# remove cancel button or override cancel button function from local notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

s it possible to remove cancel button or

override cancel button function from

local notification view?If yes then how we can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can not remove cancel button. You have only option to remove
>   action button not cancel button  and As it is defined in
>   implementation file of UILocalNotification so u can not override it.

Answer (score 0):

you have only ok button for UILocalNotification by doing this

```
notif.hasAction=NO;
```

by doing this you cannot see view button in the notifications. Hope it solved your Problem